# JavaScript: Get element's size if it's not explicitly defined via CSS

Tags: javascript, css

Is there any way I can get current html element dimensions (width/height) if they are not explicitly defined in CSS? Using just JavaScript? For example if I have image

```
var image = document.getElementsByClassName("top-image")[0];
```

And let's say I have click event. How can I get dimensions in the moment when event happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`image.getBoundingClientRect()` More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect